# Designer not working with MySQL relations only

Tags: mysql, relation

could you please help me with the following issue:

I've set up a database with 2 tables in it and I'm trying to create a relationship between them. The engine is InnoDB, the toggle relationship is on but still no relation between the values. When I click on referenced and foreign keys the message for confirmation is showing- I confirm the relations but nothing happened.

If someone has some kind of solution please share. 
Thank you in advance.

create relation:

[image: create relation]

view after relation created:
[image: view after relation created]

Comment: What tool do you use there?

Comment: use create relationship options

Answer (score 0):

I`m using XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.4.

I`ve used create relationship but no relations has occured.
 Probably some setting is not configured properly.